# Push paragraphs down to not overlap with page header in MigraDoc 1.5b3

Tags: c#, migradoc

The code below aims to add an image and date stamp to the page header and then populate the page with some text (for example one header and a couple of paragraphs).

The problem is that the text overlaps the page header, it starts at the same height as the date stamp paragraph in the page header. What am I doing wrong?

```
Section section = document.AddSection();
section.PageSetup.StartingNumber = 1;

Image image = section.Headers.Primary.AddImage(GetImageFromDB("LogoPageHeader")); // creates base64 encoded image string
image.LockAspectRatio = true;
image.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
image.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
image.Top = ShapePosition.Top;
image.Left = ShapePosition.Left;
image.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.TopBottom; // to push date stamp to below the bottom of the image

HeaderFooter header = section.Headers.Primary;
Paragraph paragraph = header.AddParagraph(DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;

Paragraph paragraph = document.LastSection.AddParagraph("Question Summary:", "Heading3");

paragraph = document.LastSection.AddParagraph();
paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
paragraph.AddText("Question: " + q.Text.Trim());

paragraph = document.LastSection.AddParagraph();
paragraph.Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Left;
paragraph.AddText("Answer: " + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(q.ReplyText.Trim()) ? q.ReplyCode.ToString() : q.ReplyText.Trim()));
paragraph.Format.SpaceAfter = "8pt";
```

The image is about 20x20mm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the TopMargin of the PageSetup to reserve space for the header.

See also:
http://forum.pdfsharp.net/viewtopic.php?p=3077

Comment: Just to preserve the linked code: `section.PageSetup.BottomMargin = Unit.FromCentimeter(x)`